# Swift Bool Function return will never executed

Tags: swift, boolean

I want to create a code which can determine whether the character is one of the symbols in my list.

```
var symbols = ["+","-"]
func issymbol(last:String ) -> Bool{
    return true
    for i in 0...(symbols.count){
    if last == symbols[i]{
       return false
    }
    }
}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Use array's contains property.

Comment: You're returning true immediately without running the for loop. Move it to the end.

Answer (score 1):

**No code execute after return keyword. so I update your code try this**

```
var symbols = ["+","-"]
    func issymbol(last:String ) -> Bool{
        for value in symbols {
            if last == value {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `return true` at the end and it will execute `if last == symbols[i]{` never met. So update your code as shown below:

```
func issymbol(last:String) -> Bool{
    for i in 0...(symbols.count){
        if last == symbols[i]{
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

issymbol(last: "+")  //false
```

Or you can use `contains` property for that:

```
func issymbol(last:String) -> Bool{

    return !symbols.contains(last)
}

issymbol(last: "+") // false
issymbol(last: "1") // true
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot issues in this code.

1. The line `return true` returns immediately so the check won't be performed (the error message).
2. The line `for i in 0...(symbols.count)` will crash because the index starts at 0 and the last index is `symbols.count - 1`. Alternatively you can write `for i in 0..<symbols.count`. 
   The best syntax is not to write an index based loop:

   ```
   for symbol in symbols { if last == symbol ...
   ```
3. If the item is found the code returns `false` rather than `true`.
4. The code doesn't return a `Bool` **after** the loop if the item was not found (will cause another error).

The correct code is

```
let symbols = ["+","-"]

func issymbol(last: String) -> Bool {
    for i in 0...symbols.count - 1 {
        if last == symbols[i] {
           return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

However this can be reduced to

```
func issymbol(last: String) -> Bool {
    return symbols.contains(last)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions only execute until they reach a return statement. Xcode detected that the rest of the code in that function won't be executed, because your function will always return after the first line. You probably meant something like this:

```
var symbols = ["+","-"]
func issymbol(last:String ) -> Bool{
    for i in 0...(symbols.count){
        if last == symbols[i]{
           return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Because the return statement is after the for loop, the for loop can execute. This function will return true if the string you pass in is *not* in the symbols array.